# Search for values of IDs using preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I get a string in PHP and I need to look up the values of the IDs, can be 1, how can be 100 IDs, how to do? I tried something like this:

```
$text = 'Name1 <span id="indicado-b">John</span> Name2 <span id="indicado-c">Mike</span>';
preg_match_all('/<span id="indicado-(.*)"/si',$text, $match);
print_r($match);
```

The value that I need to receive is `b` and `c`, which are the ID values, but it is not returning this, I get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => John Name2 Array ( [0] => b">John Name2
```

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't get Mike in the result too.

Comment: Use non-greedy quantifier, or better a negated character class, see https://3v4l.org/Oc5Lu

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```php
$text = 'Name1 <span id="indicado-b">John</span> Name2 <span id="indicado-c">Mike</span>';
$separate_array = explode('<span id="indicado-', $text);

$span_ids = array();
foreach ($separate_array as $row) {
    $test_span = explode('"', $row);
    if (count($test_span) > 1 ) {
        $span_ids[] = $test_span[0];
    }
}
print_r($span_ids);
```

It returns the result as you expected using `explode` in PHP.